# PHP hash_hmac() binary output with crypto-js

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I'm developing a project with an app (expo react native) and a server Laravel 5.1, using `oauth2-server`.
Now I need to send Authorization header with format

```
Mac id="access_token" ts="timestamp" nonce="random_string" mac="signature"
```

My problem is the `signature` is not match with calculated signature from oauth-server. I also compared all necessary parts of signarure (request URI, Host and Port). They are matched

I'm trying to generate encoded base64 with `crypto-js`. Result string must be equal with result of `hash_hmac()` in PHP. Below is example

```
$phpString = base64_encode(
    hash_hmac(
        'sha256', 'ANY STRING', 'HMAC HASH KEY', true
    )
);
// Result: cOeqRLpcqCUyluyY/Y4yROM+5upAr0dFzrSLU/m8qhY=
```

In my JS script with `crypto-js`

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import Base64   from 'crypto-js/enc-base64';

const jsString = Base64.stringify(
    CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('ANY STRING', 'HMAC HASH KEY').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
);
// 70e7aa44ba5ca8253296ec98fd8e3244e33ee6ea40af4745ceb48b53f9bcaa16
// It is seems not a valid base64 string
```

I also tried with some other scripts, and It was not working

```
const jsString = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('ANY STRING', 'HMAC HASH KEY').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
// cOeqRLpcqCUyluyY/Y4yROM+5upAr0dFzrSLU/m8qhY=
```

Two results are totally different. What is my wrong in JS script?

Comment: Just to make things a little easier, since you've already run all three of these, can you [edit] your question to also provide what each of their output was?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I just have updated results of scripts, also why do I need to do. I have been looking for any solutions.

Comment: The second node.js script's output matches the PHP's output though...?

Comment: Let me re-check. I'm confusing now

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you for your help. `crypto-js` return encoded string correctly. Have a mistake of input